# Show the principal ideal $(x+y\omega)$ has no prime ideal factor in common with other principal ideal $(x+y\omega ^j)$ for $j=0$ or $j=2,...,p-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Show that the principal ideal $(x+y\omega)$ in $\mathbb Z[\omega]$ has no prime ideal factor in common with any of the other principal ideals on the left side of the equation
$$(x+y)(x+y\omega)(x+y\omega^2)\cdots(x+y\omega ^{p-1})=x^p+y^p,$$
where $p$ is an odd prime and $\omega=e^{2\pi i/p}$.

I came across this problem in a book called $\textit{Number Field}$. I think this problem may use the fact that ideals factor uniquely (up to order) into prime ideals. However, I don't know how to use it.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Where did you come across this problem? And in which ring(s) should these ideals live?